# Spring @Async on implementation method not executing

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have a service interface and implementation class. When I annotate an interface method with @Async, it works properly. However, when I annotate a method on the implementing class, the call to the method returns immediately, but no code in the method actually gets run. Spring's documentation examples show the annotation used on implemented methods, but it's not working that way for me.

Comment: Are you calling the asynchronous method from within the same implementation class?

Comment: No, I am calling it from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it is supposed to work that is why it asyncronous. Did you put any break point to your Async annotated class. Put a system out log and make sure that it is not being called actually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done everything correctly you may have this issue:  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10715